# Java - Tabla de días de la semana por mes. Me he quedado pillado y no se avanzar

Tags: java

Estamos en el tema de los arrays. Os pongo el enunciado y un ejemplo.

Nos han pedido que generemos una tabla en forma de array bidimensional donde las filas sean los meses del año (doce) y las columnas los días de la semana (siete). De este modo, para un año concreto, en cada casilla de la tabla habrá que almacenar, para cada mes, cuántos lunes tiene, cuántos martes, cuántos miércoles, etc.

Para ello habrá que escribir un programa en Java que:

Reserve espacio en memoria para la tabla (array bidimensional de 12x7). Podemos imaginar ese array como una tabla de contadores donde inicialmente cada contador estará a cero.

Solicite por teclado el año para el cual se quiere calcular la tabla. Debe ser un año entre 1900 y 2100, ambos incluidos. Si no se introduce un año correcto, deberá volverse a pedir hasta que sea correcto.

A partir de ahí, habrá que idear un mecanismo para recorrer cada día del año y, en función del mes y del día de la semana que se trate, incrementar el contador (celda de la tabla) correspondiente.

Una vez la tabla esté completamente rellena (se han recorrido todos los días del año), habrá que mostrarla por pantalla con un formato apropiadamente tabulado y con una cabecera para las filas (número de mes) y otra para las columnas (una letra para cada día de la semana). Por ejemplo, para el año 2022 podríamos obtener algo así:

L M X J V S D
Mes 1 5 4 4 4 4 5 5
Mes 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
Mes 3 4 5 5 5 4 4 4
Mes 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 4
Mes 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 5
Mes 6 4 4 5 5 4 4 4
Mes 7 4 4 4 4 5 5 5
Mes 8 5 5 5 4 4 4 4
Mes 9 4 4 4 5 5 4 4
Mes 10 5 4 4 4 4 5 5
Mes 11 4 5 5 4 4 4 4
Mes 12 4 4 4 5 5 5 4

Como puedes observar, todo mes tiene siempre entre cuatro y cinco lunes, martes, miércoles,

Y mi código de momento es este, pero me he quedado pillado y no se avanzar.

```
public class Ejercicio04 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static int[][] tabla = new int[12][7];
    private static LocalDate calendario;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //----------------------------------------------
        //          Declaración de variables 
        //----------------------------------------------
        // Constantes

        
        
        // Variables de entrada

        
        // Variables de salida
        // 1. Declaramos la tabla para almacenar el resultado (array de int de tamaño 12x7)

        
        // Variables auxiliares

        
        // Objeto Scanner para lectura desde teclado
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        //----------------------------------------------
        //                Entrada de datos 
        //----------------------------------------------
        System.out.println("NÚMERO DE DÍAS DE LA SEMANA POR MES");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

        // 2. Solicitamos por teclado el año
        // Leer y comprobar el año (1900 y 2023), ambos incluidos

        int año = 0;
    while (año < 1900 || año > 2100) {
    
            try {
            System.out.print("Introduzca año (1900-2100): ");
            año = Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
            if (año < 1900 || año > 2100)
            System.out.println("Error de lectura: valor ha de ser entre 1900 y 2100");}
        
            catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error de lectura: no es un número entero valido.");}
        }
            
        teclado.close();
        
        
        //----------------------------------------------
        //               Procesamiento
        //----------------------------------------------
        // 3. Recorremos todos los días del año (bucle) y calculamos cuántos días de semana (L,M,X, etc.) hay por mes

        for (int mes = 0; mes < 12; mes++) {
            for (int dia = 0; dia < 7; dia++) { 
            calendario = LocalDate.of(año, mes + 1, 1);
            int contador = 0;
            while (calendario.getMonthValue() - 1 == mes) {
            if (calendario.getDayOfWeek().getValue() - 1 == dia) contador++;
            calendario = calendario.plusDays(1);}
            
        int[] diasMes = new int[contador];
    
        calendario = LocalDate.of(año, mes + 1, 1);
    contador = 0; 
        
        while (calendario.getMonthValue() - 1 == mes) {
            if (calendario.getDayOfWeek().getValue() - 1 == dia) {
            diasMes[contador] = calendario.getDayOfMonth();
            contador++;}
            
            calendario = calendario.plusDays(1);}
        
        tabla[mes][dia] = diasMes;}
    }
        

        //----------------------------------------------
        //            Salida de resultados  
        //----------------------------------------------
        System.out.println("RESULTADO AÑO: " + año);

        // 4. Mostramos el contenido de la tabla resultado de manera tabulada
        // 4.1. Cabecera de la tabla
            
        System.out.printf(" L M X J V S D\n");

        // 4.2. Filas repetitivas (una por mes)
        
        for (int mes = 0; mes < 12; mes++) {
            System.out.printf("Mes %2d", mes+1);

        
            // 4.2.1. Columnas repetititvas (una por día de la semana)
            
            for (int dia = 0; dia < 7; dia++)
        System.out.printf(" %-20s",Arrays.toString(tabla[mes][dia]));
            System.out.println();


        }
    }
 
}
```

A ver si me podéis echar una mano.

Gracias

Comment: "Me faltan cosas que no entiendo" es una pésima descripción para el problema que quieres resolver. Especifica el problema. Si lo pones como un ejercicio de revisión de tu código para que te digan qué añadir, quienes están por aquí no lo van a recibir bien. Recuerda que puedes [edit]

Comment: Me he quedado pillado y no se avanzar

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: La pregunta no está del todo bien formulada, lo cual hace que sea complicado de entender tu problema. Te recomiendo leerte [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y editar la pregunta.